# Is A truly better than B, given that 56% of 131 respondednts said so?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, proportion

I have asked subjects whether procedure A is better than procedure B. Slightly more said yes (56% of a group of 131 subjects). How can I tell if this answer tells me that indeed procedure A is better than B, instead of the students just randomizing their answers?

Comment: Somewhat pedantic, but you can't tell whether or not procedure A is better from this survey. All you can say is if students *prefer* it by a significant margin. A "no homework" policy, for example, would likely be popular with students, but may well be worse than the alternative for learning outcomes.

Comment: Z-test for proportion. This links explains it all: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/statprogram/node/164/

Comment: Binomial confidence intervals...

Comment: @NuclearWang very pedantic!

Comment: @stans Thank you. Any ideas how to implement it in Stata?

Comment: Stata command `prtesti`. You can get to it through the menu as well.

Comment: So I ran a binomial porbability test using bitest VSC=0.5. It told me that   Pr(k >= 72)            = 0.108781  (one-sided test). I am trying to interpret the result. Does it say that "the probability of observing 72 or more YES on the sample conditional on random choice (p=0.5) is very small? What is the right interpretation for this?

Comment: It seems you have the correct Stata procedure. Also seems in my Answer (not having seen your Comment before I started), I guessed 56% of 131 as 73, when I should have guessed 72. But that wouldn't change the interpretation at the 5% level.

Comment: @NuclearWang Not pedantic at all. Sloppy stats-based reasoning is the bane of education research, including a tendency to draw conclusions which go beyond what the data can actually says.

Comment: @Nuclear Wang Excellent comment. In some social sciences people also wish to avoid biasing the study subjects by asking "is B better than A" at a later point of the questionnaire to check for consistency in answers.

Comment: *"How can I tell if this answer tells me that indeed procedure A is better than B?"* I have a comment/question along the lines of @NuclearWang. **What do you mean by 'procedure A is better than B'?** Do you imagine the world like there is an objective answer to 'A is better than B' and all 44% of the subjects that said the opposite are wrong'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have $X = 73$ out of $n = 131$ favoring A over B. Then a 95%
Agresti-Coull CI for the population proportion $p$ favoring A is of the form
$$\check p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\check p(1-\check p)}{\check n}},$$
where $\check n = n+ 4$ and $\check p = \frac{X+2}{n+4}.$
This computes to $(.472, .639),$ which includes 50%.

```
p.ac = 75/135; n.ac = 135; pm=c(-1,1)
p.ac + pm*1.96*(sqrt(p.ac*(1-p.ac)/n.ac))
[1] 0.4717328 0.6393783
```

Testing the null hypothesis $H_0: p = 1/2$ against the *one-sided* alternative
$H_a: p > 1/2,$ one obtains the P-value $P(X \ge 73) = 1 - P(X \le 72) \approx 0.11$ (under the assumption $H_0$ is true). Even though 65% > 50%, it appears
the 56% is not *significantly greater* that 50% at the 5% level.

This can be computed in R as follows:

```
1 - pbinom(72, 131, .5)
[1] 0.110558
```

More formally, the exact binomial test `binom.test` in R, gives this P-value
along with a one-sided 95% CI (that is a 95% lower bound).

```
binom.test(73, 131, alte="g")

        Exact binomial test

data:  73 and 131
number of successes = 73, number of trials = 131, p-value =
0.1106
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4816258 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.5572519
```

*Addendum;* Sometimes a 95% Bayesian posterior probability ('credible') interval
based on a 'non-informative' or 'flat' prior distribution, such as $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1) \equiv \mathsf{Beta}(1,1),$ is used by frequentist statisticians as a 95% confidence interval. I mention this partly for completeness and partly because @MatthewDrury almost seems to suggest a Bayesian framework in his answer (+1).

For $X = 73$ and $n - X = 58,$ this interval estimate
can be computed by finding quantiles 0.025 and 0.975 of $\mathsf{Beta}(X+1, n-X+1).$ Specifically, $(0.472, 0.640),$ which is numerically very similar to the Agresti-Coull interval mentioned above.

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 74, 59)
[1] 0.4716082 0.6395668
```

*Note:* For more on binomial interval estimates see [this Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774396/is-a-90-confidence-interval-really-90-confident/1774550#1774550) and its References.

Answer (score 9):

First, @NuclearWang is correct.  If your survey is as stated, you're learning about what procedure people prefer, not what is better (for some unspecified purpose).  I don't think it's a pedantic point, its important to measure what we intend to measure.

The statistics here is pretty simple.  You want to know if your data indicates that the respondents were not guessing randomly.  The standard approach is to assume that they **are** guessing randomly (usually called the *null hypothesis*), then show that your data is very unlikely to have been collected under that hypothesis.

Under the random guessing assumption, your data would be generated from a binomial process:

$$ \text{# of votes for A} \sim \text{Binomial}(n = 131, p = 0.5) $$

You actually observed $72$ votes for A.  We can easily calculate the probability that we would observe greater than or equal to $72$ votes for A if the respondents were guessing randomly.  I'll use python:

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as stats

In [2]: 1 - stats.binom(n=131, p=0.5).cdf(71)
Out[2]: 0.14720307826175671
```

It looks like there's a 15% chance of observing data equal or more extreme than you actually collected when the respondents were guessing randomly.  How you use this probability to affect your beliefs is up to you.

Comment: "How you use this probability to affect your beliefs is up to you."
But typically you fix a signficance level _up front_ (say, 10% or 5% or 2,5%) and reject your null hypothesis if the probability of observing your outcome is lower than the significance level. It is important to do this before you calculate or even measure to make sure that you don't "fix the result to the observation". However, 15% is higher than most typical significance levels so normally in your case you would accept the null hypothesis here and say that 56% is within normal expectations for 131 randomly guessing students

Comment: @CompuChip It's true that setting a threshold is standard practice.  As you can probably guess by my leaving it out of the answer, I have mixed feelings about it!  I suppose setting an alpha level and following the NHST approach is wrapped up in "is up to you".

Comment: Matthew, I am sure there are pros and cons - most of which I'm probably not aware of, so maybe that will make for an interesting question on this site. But I did want to mention it, even if just in the comments, for OPs sake in case they are unfamiliar with this technique which - feelings aside - seems to be very common.

Comment: Agreed, I think you did the right thing.  I'll happily edit your comment into my answer if you grant permission to do so.

Comment: Good answer but it's worth noting that you are computing one-sided p-value. The two-sided calculation would lead not 15% but 30%.